# Are adverbials inclined to the subject?Rather than simply modifying the verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence-structure, adverbials

> "*He writes the word **on the board**.*"

If adverbials are simply about the verb, then “on the board” in “He writes the word on the board” can be explained as **either an adverbial or an complement**, for on the board simply describes writing.

But evidently, “on the board’ is **a complement, not an adverbial**. In my understanding, adverbials are **more inclined to the subject** and meanwhile very related to the verb. So “on the board” cannot be an adverbial, for if it is, it will mean the man is **standing on the board**.

However in most grammar books, adverbials are described as merely “**modifying or defining the sentence or the verb**”, no subject here. I mean can “modifying the verb” be understood as adverbials are **inclined to the subject** or not?

Comment: "How the object is acting the verb" doesn't make any sense to me. I don't actually know what you're asking. *On the board* is a prepositional phrase; it has nothing to do with an adverb. In *he writes* ***sloppily***, *sloppily* is an adverb that modifies the writing. There is no adverb in your example sentence.

Comment: @JasonBassford Some frameworks use the term "adverbial" in the same sense as "adjunct". A PP and an AdvP, therefore, can both function as adverbial. Inorganic_Salt, please explain what you mean by "acting the verb".

Comment: Also note that the example sentence does *not* mean he is standing on a board. To express that, you would need to say *he writes the word **while standing** on the board*. In fact, *while standing on the board* could be considered an adverbial phrase. But not just *on the board* in the example  sentence (which mentions nothing about standing in the first place).

Comment: Sure, if we separate the two as follows, *"A complement is a necessary element, whereas an adverbial is an optional element,"* then this is definitely a **complement**.  Is there some reason why this is important to you?

Comment: Sorry I mistook”object” for “subject, I actually mean “subject. I edited my Q so it’s easier to understand. It’s so kind of you to spend time on my question. @JasonBassford I know the sentence is usually understood as "the word is on the board',(also we can avoid ambiguity easily even if ambiguity occurs) but I wanna know can “modifying the verb” be understood as adverbials are inclined to the subject or not? Thanks so much